# Row echelon form question

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am wondering if there is a Mathematica command that will put a matrix in row echelon form. That is, put

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 3 & 4\\
-1 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in row echelon form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
I am aware that I can do a sequence of elementary row operations. I am also aware of the `RowReduce` command which puts a matrix in **reduced** row echelon form. I even saw a `Method -> "OneStepRowReduction"` used by the `RowReduce` command which I thought might be the choice.

Just wondering if there is a command for this that I cannot find.

Comment: Your second matrix is not in row echelon form.

Comment: What @enzotib quite correctly observes leads me to wonder if perhaps you actually want the "echelon" form over the ring of integers. That would be found with `HermiteDecomposition`.

Comment: Fixed the row echelon error. Sorry about that. No, I just want the ordinary row echelon form students have to do when first introduced to Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Note that there is nothing unique about a row echelon form, even such a form whose leading entries are all 1. So the question needs to be restated in a more precise manner. E.g., do you want a command that follows a particular algorithm for obtaining a row echelon form? As you noted, it's easy to do a sequence of elementary row operations, and to write little functions to do such operations, then to write a main function that calls those little functions to follow a particular reduction algorithm. But then how do you want to handle roundoff errors? (Or do you want exact rational arithmetic?)

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228098/how-to-write-a-more-concise-rowreduce-function-that-can-deal-with-symbolic-mat)'s a question similar to yours.

Answer (score 3):

I think `LUDecomposition` should be able to do this. Using code from help in Mathematica docs:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {-1, 0, 2}};
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[a]
(u = lu SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j >= i -> 1, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want all pivots to be +1, this can now be easily done.

```
d = Position[Diagonal[u], -1]
(u[[First@#]] = -u[[First@#]]) & /@ d
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240360/how-to-correctly-enumerate-all-the-schemes-of-this-cube-coloring-problem/240404?noredirect=1#comment607016_240404) is a similar question for reference only. The following code uses Gaussian elimination method to obtain the row echelon form:

```
rref[A_?MatrixQ] := Module[{a, m, n, i, j, k, l, L, B},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[A]; B = A;
  Print[MatrixForm@A];
  i = 1; k = 1; While[i <= m,(*i表示行*)
   While[k < n && B[[i ;;, k]] == ConstantArray[0, m - i + 1], k++; 
    If[k == n && B[[i ;;, k]] == ConstantArray[0, m - i + 1], 
     Return[B]]];(*k表示列, 如果全是0, 考察下一列, 如果最后一列也是0, 退出函数*)
   For[l = i, l <= m, l++, 
    If[(a = B[[l, k]]) != 0 && k < n && 
      B[[l, (k + 1) ;;]] == ConstantArray[0, n - k], B[[l, k]] = 1; 
     Print["第(1)", l, "行除以", a, "->", MatrixForm@B];]];
   If[Length[a = DeleteCases[B[[i ;;, k]], 0]] != 0, 
    If[Length[Cases[Abs[a], 1]] != 0, L = 1, 
     If[Length[Cases[Abs[a], GCD @@ a]] != 0, L = Abs[GCD @@ a], 
      L = Abs[First[a]];](*如果有公因式就选取这个数, 不然选第一个不为零的数*), 
     Return[B]]];(*选取第一个不为0的数, 如果下边都成了0, 退出函数*)
   j = i; While[j < m && Abs[B[[j, k]]] != L, j++;];(*找到所在的行, 用j表示*)
   If[i != j, If[B[[j, k]] != 0, B[[{i, j}, ;;]] = B[[{j, i}, ;;]];
     Print["第", i, "行和第", j,
      "行换行->", MatrixForm@B], Return[B]](*都是0, 返回*)];(*换行: i<->j*)
   For[l = k, l <= m, l++, 
    If[(a = B[[l, k]]) != 0 && l != i && B[[i, k]] != 0, 
     B[[l, ;;]] = B[[l, ;;]] - B[[l, k]]/B[[i, k]] B[[i, ;;]];
     
     Print["第", l, "行加第", i, "行的", -a, "倍-> " MatrixForm@B]]]; i++;];
  
  Return[B];]
```

```
    A = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {-1, 0, 2}}
    rref[A]
```

[image]

Comment: Why are there foreign characters in the solution?