# How to transform symmetric matrix to diagonal?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I wonder whether there is a way how to transform symmetric matrix to diagonal matrix using symetretric transformation. I could not find any function that performs symmetric transformation in Mathematica.

E.g. I have matrix `{{1,a},{a,2}}` and I want to do `TransformToDiagonal[{{1,a},{a,2}}]`. The result should be `{{1,0},{0,2-a^2}}`.

---

Definitions: Symmetric transformation is a finite sequence of elementary symmetric operations. By elementary symmetric operation we mean applying elementary row operation and then the corresponding column operation.

Comment: How did you get the this result`{{1,0},{0,2-a^2}}
`?

Comment: I added (-a)*1st row to 2nd row and then (-a)*1st column to 2nd column.

Comment: Are you talking about row reduced echelon?

Comment: Kind of, but I need to use symmetric transformation. At the end, I should have zeros everywhere except for the diagonal.

Comment: You said _I added (-a)*1st row to 2nd row and then (-a)*1st column to 2nd column._ But how can you get this `{{1,0},{0,2-a^2}}`  as a result?

Comment: I have `{{1,0},{a,2}}`. I add -a*1st row to 2nd row so I have `{{1,a},{a-a=0,2-a^2}}` . Then I add  -a*1st row to column to 2nd column so I get `{{1,0},{0,2-a^2}}`. I am sorry if it is not clear, I dont learn mathematics in English.

Comment: You wrote wrong matrix in question?

Comment: The matrix in question is right {{1,a},{a,2}}. I wrote wrong matrix in the comment...

Comment: What _exactly_ to you mean by "symmetric transformation"? There are infinitely many transformations which map a symmetric matrix to a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Possibly [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83469/mathbf-l-mathbf-d-mathbf-l-top-cholesky-decomposition/92502).

Comment: @anderstood Symmetric transformation is a finite sequence of elementary symmetric operations. By elementary symmetric operation we mean applying elementary row operation and then the corresponding column operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we need to check whether the matrix in question is symmetric or not.

```
SymmetricMatrixQ[{{1, a}, {a, 2}}]
```

> True

Now we will go for row reduction to see what we get,

```
RowReduce[{{1, a}, {a, 2}}] // MatrixForm
```

> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 
> \end{pmatrix}

This is not what you want. Now I will try Nassers [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77903/row-echelon-form-question) to use `LUDecomposition`

```
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[{{1, a}, {a, 2}}]
(u = lu SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j >= i -> 1, {2, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & a \\
> 0 & 2-a^2 
> \end{pmatrix}

I maybe wrong but it seems what you are after is impossible for me to produce.

**Edit**

Following @george2079 suggestions, we can get the OPs desired result,

```
Transpose[u];
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[%];
(u = lu SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j >= i -> 1, {2, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 2-a^2 
> \end{pmatrix}

Comment: This seems to be working well-enough for 2x2 matrices (probably because in this case the "column" part of a symmetric transformation does not change the diagonal) , but gives completely wrong results for bigger ones. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: `Transpose` and repeat the `LUDecomposition` approach.. gives the same result as my answer.

Comment: @george2079 Wow!. Thanks

Comment: @velblúd You should accept  george2079 response as an answer not mine. I adopted his idea.

Comment: Thank you guys. I accepted this answer as it is nicer and more robust that the procedural approach.

Answer (score 2):

kind of ugly procedural approach:

```
n = 3
m = Table[ a[Min[i, j], Max[i, j] ], {i, n}, {j, n}] ;
Do[ m[[row]] = m[[row]] - m[[prow]]  m[[row, prow]]/m[[prow, prow]]
   , {prow, 1, n - 1} , {row, {prow + 1, n} }];
m = Transpose[m];
Do[ m[[row]] = m[[row]] - m[[prow]]  m[[row, prow]]/m[[prow, prow]]
   , {prow, 1, n - 1} , {row, {prow + 1, n} }];
```

> m // MatrixForm

[image]

of course for `m={{1, a}, {a, 2}}` this yields `{{1, 0}, {0, 2 - a^2}}`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need! Just one note - it fails if there is zero on the diagonal. (e.g. {{0,1},{0,1}}). But this  is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

another approach

```
m = {{1, a}, {a, 2}};
Nest[(Transpose@UpperTriangularize@First@LUDecomposition@#) &, m, 2]
{{1, 0}, {0, 2 - a^2}}
```

With @george2079 matrix:

```
n = 3
m = Table[a[Min[i, j], Max[i, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}];
Nest[(Transpose@UpperTriangularize@First@LUDecomposition@#) &, m, 
  2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]