# How to write a more concise `RowReduce` function that can deal with symbolic matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

I asked a similar question in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227929/how-to-solve-this-equation-with-rank-relation-of-matrix) before and understand the reason why `RowReduce` function can't reduce symbolic matrix.

I wrote an `RowReduce` function that can handle symbolic matrices:

```
exchanges[v1_, v2_] := 
 Module[{t}, 
  t = InversePermutation[PermutationList[FindPermutation[v1, v2]]]; 
  If[t != {}, 
   Select[MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, 
     LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`PermutationToPivot[t]], Apply[Unequal]], {}]]

matrixWrapOperation[mat_, rule_] := 
 Module[{B = mat}, 
  If[rule != {}, 
   Do[B[[{Keys[rule[[n]]], Values[rule[[n]]]}, ;;]] = 
     B[[{Values[rule[[n]]], Keys[rule[[n]]]}, ;;]];
    Print["Swap the elements in row", Keys[rule[[n]]], "and row ", 
     Values[rule[[n]]], "->", MatrixForm@B], {n, 1, Length[rule]}]; B,
    B]]

rref[A_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{sysa, sysm, sysn, sysi, sysj, sysk, sysl, sysL, sysB},
  {sysm, sysn} = Dimensions[A]; sysB = A;
  Print[MatrixForm@A];
  
  (*Below is the preprocessing sort\[DownArrow]*)
  Print["Start preprocessing"];
  sysB = matrixWrapOperation[A, 
    exchanges[
     A[[;; , 1]], (SortBy[A /. {0 -> Infinity}, 
         First] /. {Infinity -> 0})[[All, 1]]]];
  Print["End of preprocessing"];
  (*The above is the preprocessing sort\[UpArrow]*)
  
  sysi = 1(*sysi represents the row number*); 
  sysk = 1(*sysk represents the column number*); While[sysi <= sysm,
   While[sysk < sysn && 
     sysB[[sysi ;;, sysk]] == ConstantArray[0, sysm - sysi + 1], sysk++;
     If[sysk == sysn && sysB[[sysi ;;, sysk]] == 0, Return[sysB]; 
     Goto[end]]];
   
   
   (*For[sysl=sysi,sysl\[LessEqual]sysm,sysl++,If[(sysa=sysB[[sysl,
   sysk]])\[NotEqual]0&&sysk<sysn&&sysB[[
   sysl,(sysk+1);;]]\[Equal]ConstantArray[0,sysn-sysk],sysB[[sysl,
   sysk]]=1;Print["Divide all elements in row",sysl," by ",sysa,"->",
   MatrixForm@sysB];]];*)
   
   
   sysa = DeleteCases[sysB[[sysi ;;, sysk]], 0]; 
   If[Length[sysa] == 0, sysL = 1, sysL = First[sysa]];
   
   
   
   sysj = sysi; 
   While[sysj < sysm && sysB[[sysj, sysk]] =!= sysL, sysj++;];
   
   If[sysi != sysj, 
    If[sysB[[sysj, sysk]] =!= 0, 
     sysB[[{sysi, sysj}, ;;]] = sysB[[{sysj, sysi}, ;;]];
     Print["Swap the elements in row", sysi, "and row ", sysj, "->", 
      MatrixForm@sysB], Return[sysB]]
    ];
   
   
   
   For[sysl = sysi, sysl <= sysm, sysl++, 
    If[(sysa = sysB[[sysl, sysk]]) =!= 0 && sysl > sysi, 
     sysB[[sysl, ;;]] = 
      sysB[[sysl, ;;]] - 
       sysB[[sysl, sysk]]/sysB[[sysi, sysk]] sysB[[sysi, ;;]];
     
     Print["The ", sysl, " row of elements plus ", -(sysa/sysL), 
      " times the ", sysi, " row of elements", 
      "-> " MatrixForm@sysB]]];
   sysi++(*Outermost row loop count*);]; Label[end];
  
  Return[sysB];]
```

**Examples for testing:**

```
A = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {4, 4}]; 
rref[A]
rref[{{1, 9, 7, 2}, {0, 2, -(9/2), 
    2}, {0, -(11/2), -(11/2), -t}, 
       {s, 10, 9, 7}, {1, 2, 4, 3}}]

rref[{{8, 0, 0, 1, 3}, {8, 0, 0, 0, 3}, 
       {6, 0, 0, 2, 4}, {7, 0, 0, 8, 9}, 
       {10, 0, 0, 1, 5}}]

rref[{{1, -1, -1}, {2, a, 1}, {-1, 1, a}}]

rref[{{1, -1, -1, 2, 2}, {2, a, 1, 1, a}, {-1, 1, a, -a - 1, -2}}]
```

But the above code is too cumbersome. Is there a more concise way to realize the function of `rref` function?

Comment: One concise possibility is, well, 'RowReduce'. You should therefore explain why it is not suitable.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau For example: the row simplest form of matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ should be $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & a-2 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ instead of $\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$.  `RowReduce[{{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]
rref[{{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]`

Comment: Perhaps the point to emphasize is that `RowReduce` seems to make the generic assumption that any expression that is not literally zero is nonzero.

Comment: @Montevideo Perhaps you should refer to your previous question (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/227929/43522) to clarify the problem. As it stands, this question doesn't explain the problem very well.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thank you very much for your advice. I have updated the question.

Comment: Please stop making many tiny edits to this post.  It inappropriately bumps it up the active questions page *and* generates moderator flags that have to be handled.  Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will hardly edit this post any more. If you have time, I hope you can write a custom function to solve my problem. If you don't have time, it doesn't matter. Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this, but I'm unsure how safe it is to treat `a - 2` as zero:

```
mat = {{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}};
RowReduce[mat,
 ZeroTest -> (Quiet[Length@Solve[# == 0, Reals] > 0] &)]
```

> $$
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 0 & 2-a \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2-a \\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$

There's also

```
UpperTriangularize@First@LUDecomposition@mat
```

> $$
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & a & 2 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2-a \\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$

The columns are not reduced. Also, I suspect `LUDecomposition` would divide by `a - 2` if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I hope your method can handle the following situation:`mat = {{1, -1, -1, 2, 2}, {2, a, 1, 1, a}, {-1, 1, a, -a - 1, -2}}; RowReduce[mat, ZeroTest -> (Quiet[Length@Solve[# == 0, Reals] > 0] &)]`.  
Reference answer: $\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & a & 1 & 1 & a \\
-1 & 1 & a & -a-1 & -2
\end{array}\right) \rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & a+2 & 3 & -3 & a-4 \\
0 & 0 & a-1 & 1-a & 0
\end{array}\right)$

Comment: I hope it can handle it, too, but there are doubts. Nonetheless: `Take[UpperTriangularize@First@LUDecomposition@ArrayReshape[mat, {5, 5}], 3]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, your code works very well.

Comment: I also have a problem, for the following case, can not be simplified to the simplest form and output error message:`Take[UpperTriangularize@
  First@LUDecomposition@
    ArrayReshape[{{0, 0, c1}, {1, -1, c3}, {-1, 1, c4}}, {3, 3}], 3]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If you can, I hope you can write a concise custom function to perfectly deal with the row reduction problem of the symbol matrix.

Comment: @Montevideo I'm not sure exactly what you want. I'm pretty sure the built-in functions as I've shown them, do something close, but not exactly the same. If your requirements differ too greatly or cannot be relaxed, you may have to write your own custom function. I don't have time to do that. I can help show what's done easily, though.  For instance, clearing denominators: `# * PolynomialLCM @@@ Denominator[#] &@ Take[UpperTriangularize@First@LUDecomposition@ArrayReshape[{{0, 0, c1}, {1, -1, c3}, {-1, 1, c4}}, {3, 3}], 3]`

Comment: Thank you very much. I mean that the reduction result of $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & \mathbf{c} 1 \\
\mathbf{1} & -1 & \mathbf{c} 3 \\
-1 & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{c} 4
\end{array}\right)$ should be $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 1 & c 4 \\
0 & 0 & c 3+c 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ rather than $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & c 3 \\
0 & 0 & c 1 \\
0 & 0 & c 3+c 4
\end{array}\right)$.  The calculation result of `LUDecomposition` function does not meet the requirements. So I would like to ask you to write a perfect row reduction function.

Comment: However, your free time is very limited. I will try to rewrite and improve this custom function first. If I encounter any problems, I will ask for your help. Thank you again.

Comment: @Montevideo The desired (first) result seems wrong if $c3+c4=0$ and $c1\ne0$. My result where they are both in the third column comprises  $c3+c4\ne0$ and $c1=0$ and the one just mentioned. It's technically not in row-echelon form when $c1=0$, and it's not reduced if both are nonzero. It sort of in the next-to-last step, still comprising all possibilities and waiting for the values of the $c$'s. At least that's how I understand the problem. The only way to get a completely correct result is by cases (a `Piecewise` result perhaps).

Comment: @Montevideo Thanks for the bounty!