# How to simplify a matrix with detailed steps?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

When I simplify a matrix with a parameter, for example:
[image]
(PS: it's the answer to the textbook)

When I use RowReduce[] to simplify this matrix. it seems going too far to its simplest form:
[image]

So, My question is there any way can simplify the matrix just like the textbook showing to me?

Comment: You can refer to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228098/how-to-write-a-more-concise-rowreduce-function-that-can-deal-with-symbolic-mat).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helpful~

Comment: Please include code in future (not as an image).

Comment: yep,  new fresher need time to skill the rules~